# Rails render not showing in browser, despite positive server reply

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got an issue using 'render' in Rails. I've got a custom action "search" in my controller, which is supposed to render index, as shown below.

```
def search
    @date = params[:reserve_date]
    @tables = Table.all
    render 'index'
end
```

The action is being used in a different view using the following piece of code:

```
<%= form_with url: search_tables_path do |f| %>
<%= f.date_field :reserve_date %>
<%= submit_tag "SEND" %>
<% end %>
```

After pressing the 'SEND' button, the 'index' view should be rendered. The server states:

> Rendered tables/index.html.erb within layouts/application (25.0ms)
>
> Completed 200 OK in 127ms (Views: 123.2ms | ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)

However, nothing is being displayed in the browser at all. It stays at the previous page with no change. If I try to access the index view via a link like this:

> 

Then the index view is being displayed normally, but of course I don't pass any extra information then. How can I have it render properly?

**EDIT**
Form tag in HTML appears to be complete

```
<form action="/tables/search" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="4L/RNvCzlPX8PzDGk2LXcSiyrhzXVU3cwsLUmaQvq10y9HpESbH8CX+74n/UHxLJ5LUdiWYBdoaqCb2jFIYEgw==" />
```

This is my routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  resources :tables do
  collection do
    post 'search'
    end
  end
  resources :reservations

  root 'home#index'
end
```

Comment: The action you are showing is called `search`. I thought you said you have an action called `show`. You're going to need to show how you've setup your routes.

Comment: Use your browser's "show source" feature, or an automated test, to inspect what `form_with` is generating. Is it a real, complete `<form>` tag? Edit your post and add the results.

Comment: Along with the data @Phlip asked, put the content of `config/routes.rb` as well

Comment: @lurker That's a typo, I meant 'search' action.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Forms generated with [`form_with`](http://%5B%60form_with%60%5D(http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with)) by default has `data-remote` set to `true`.

If the `data-remote` is set to `true` your form makes an AJAX call. So your view is getting rendered as the response of that AJAX call. That is why you are not getting any errors.

Add `local: true` in your `form_with`

You can learn more about `form_with` from the [docs](http://%5B%60form_with%60%5D(http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with)).

**Update:**

As [@julien-lamarche](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1611925/julien-lamarche) suggested in the comment, in the latest version of Rails, you may also need to add `data: { turbo: false }` if you are using [Turbo](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails), which is the default case in the latest version of Rails.

Comment: I think `local: true` helped, but I was missing `data: { turbo: false }` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70400988/1611925).  Albeit, I was having this bug using `form_tag`, not `form_with`

Comment: @JulienLamarche updated the answer as per the latest version of Rails. Thanks for bringing it to attention.