# Error: Form responses must redirect to another location

Tags: ruby-on-rails-7

I need to render an html code I receive from an API.

In Rails 6 : I was doing this in my controller, and it was working fine. I called the webservice I received the response, and I was redirected to the code generated by the render. Fine !

```
class GatewayController < ApplicationController
  def new
    init_gateway_call
  end

  def create
    call_gateway
    render_gateway_response
  end

  private

  ...

  def render_gateway_response
    render(html: @gateway_response.message.html_safe)
  end
end
```

new.html.erb :

```
<%= form_with url: gateway_path, local: true do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

And no : create.html.erb

** Rails 7 **

I call the webservice. I get the answer but my page idle and I get this error.

> Error: Form responses must redirect to another location at FormSubmission.requestSucceededWithResponse (application-0f0c10fb8f5683e32fc53a93a8a323c328de61682ca16fb65a6a2b8a3ba5d087.js:1614)
> at FetchRequest.receive (application-0f0c10fb8f5683e32fc53a93a8a323c328de61682ca16fb65a6a2b8a3ba5d087.js:1390)
> at FetchRequest.perform (application-0f0c10fb8f5683e32fc53a93a8a323c328de61682ca16fb65a6a2b8a3ba5d087.js:1374)

**So far, I tried:**

```
# GatewayController
respond_to :create, format: :html, gateway_response: @gateway_response.message.html_safe
```

```
<%= gateway_response %>
```

Without success ... Do you have any idea? Otherwise it is going to be a long weekend ^^

Comment: @KenWhite ... out of curiosity ... why did you remove Rails 7 since it is a problem I had while migratio, from 6.1 (it was working) to 7 (not working anymore) ?

Comment: Because the tag you added already has that information, so it is not necessary to repeat it in the title.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I figured it out you while posting my question. The error message seems like a Turbo error. I had to had data-turbo false to my form.

```
<%= form_with url: gateway_path, local: true, data: { turbo: false } do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

And keep my controller like it was.

```
render(html: @gateway_response.message.html_safe)
```

[Happy upgrade anyone](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-6-1-to-rails-7-0)

Comment: Ran into this while working on the rails getting started page for rails 5.2: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/getting_started.html

This resolved the issue.

Comment: This can only be a *temporary* hack. Turning off Turbo is not the goal. There is a bug report filed here: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/5446

Comment: Same problem in symfony ux. I fixed it by setting request forma by ```TurboBundle::STREAM_FORMAT```

Answer (score 48):

Setting `data: {turbo: false}` will cause the page to reload entirely. This takes away the entire point of turbo which is to reduce page reloads.

The reason the error occurs is because Turbo expects a `303 redirect response`. The solution is to have the server respond with `422` or `500` status code when you are not `redirecting`.

```
if save
redirect_to root_path
else
render :new, status: 422
```

You can read about this here:  https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/drive#redirecting-after-a-form-submission

Of course, if you want the page to reload, you can use `data-turbo: false`

Comment: Thanks for explanation and additional link!

Comment: This is the proper answer and it should have many more upvotes.

Comment: Hello, how to fix this issue properly? Setting data-turbo: false is, but I would like to learn the proper way. Can you please instruct me on how to fix this. Thank you

Comment: ok, I found the fix here: https://dev.to/efocoder/how-to-use-devise-with-turbo-in-rails-7-9n9

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using turbo: false as suggested on the answer you need to add appropriate status like :see_other for redirects and 422 (unprocessible_entity) in case render.

```
render :new, status: 422

redirect_to xyz_path, status: :see_other
```