# Why is Ajax request not working as intended in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following a tutorial on ruby on rails. In the tutorial the tutor is able to display the errors on saving using the `@article.erros.any` but in my case `@article.save` doesn't even finish process and i get this in my console

```
Started POST "/articles" for ::1 at 2022-12-28 16:24:05 +1100
Processing by ArticlesController#create as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "article"=>{"title"=>"", "description"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Article"}
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering articles/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered articles/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 7.7ms | Allocations: 4887)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 12.9ms | Allocations: 7084)
Completed 200 OK in 16ms (Views: 13.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 8264)
```

and this is my browser

[image]

This is my controller

```rb
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @article.destroy
    redirect_to articles_path
  end

  private

  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :description)
  end
end
```

and this is my html.erb

```rb
<h1>Create a new article</h1>
<% if @article.errors.any? %>
  <h2> The following errors prevented the article from being saved</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <%= msg %>
      <% end %>
    </li>
  </ul>
<% end %>


<%= form_with(model: @article, url: articles_path, local: true) do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :title %><br/>
    <%= form.text_field :title %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :description %> <br/>
    <%= form.text_area :description %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

I have validate in my model that should prevent submission and display the error but nothing happens

```rb
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6, maximum: 100 }
  validates :description, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10, maximum: 300 }
```

when I use `@article.save!` using the bang operator `!` it kind of works but it reloads the page

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Title can't be blank, Title is too short (minimum is 6 characters), Description can't be blank, Description is too short (minimum is 10 characters)):
  
app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:20:in `create'
Started GET "/articles/new" for ::1 at 2022-12-28 16:15:04 +1100
Processing by ArticlesController#new as HTML
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering articles/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered articles/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 1.4ms | Allocations: 969)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 5.8ms | Allocations: 3190)
Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 6.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 3446)
```

I'm really new to rails and using rails 7. searching through other issues, it doesn't appear other people are encountering this issue. Any help is appreciated

Comment: You should be able to get it working with the answers to the attached question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70400958/error-form-responses-must-redirect-to-another-location

Comment: when rendering in create or update: `render :new, status: 422`

Comment: Instead of using turbo: false as suggested on the answers linked to similar questions you need to add appropriate status like :see_other for redirects and 422 (unprocessible_entity) in case render. Same as suggested above by @Alex

Comment: @Payal `render :new, status: 422` seems to do the trick as suggest by @Alex

Comment: Awesome! Do use status: :see_other for redirect as well.